# Android Element Selection Issues

Tags: javascript, android, css

I'm attempting to make my website tablet friendly and I'm facing a strange issue.

I am testing on an Android 4.0 tablet with Chrome 30.

I have a fixed modal popover screen. While this screen is on, we don't want to let the user scroll the background so touch events are prevented. However, in this window we have a scrollable area with `overflow:scroll`, therefore the touch event is not prevented if the touch start event is detected there. So far so good - Android responsibly scrolls the area as expected.

Problem is, if the user long-presses an element inside the scroll area for about half a second, and only then scrolls - the element where the touch started appears to be selected for a moment. That selection disappears after a bit. But, in case the user scrolls *during that bit* - the whole page scrolls instead of the scrollable area. It's as if the focus is changed. What's going on?

I tried to set CSS selection rules on the elements inside but it didn't help.

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-khtml-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
```

Every other answer suggests to prevent the touch event which I can't because it's meant to be scrolled. Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it.

Add `cursor:default!important` to the above CSS rules.

I DID come across such a solution but it failed on first try. In my case, the specificity of elements inside the scrollable area was too strong, rendering `cursor:default` useless and I didn't realize it. I apply this only to mobile devices by detecting the useragent, therefore I can afford dismissing the previous `cursor` attribute with `!important` as it won't affect any desktop clients. Sweet!

Still not sure why this worked. If anyone could supply information on how the `cursor` attribute affects Chrome on Android I will be grateful.